# strong jaw doubling damage rules

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, damage

For the spell [strong jaw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strong-jaw/), when you double damage does it double dice or the total of what you rolled on the dice? Does strong jaw also double your damage modifiers like STR and can it double a double or will it only double once?

Comment: Hi Austin, welcome to the site. Can you please clarify what you mean with "double a double" ? Do you mean the spell itself being used multiple times on the same target, or is it some other effect you are asking about?

Comment: so when strong jaw doubles your damage the first time can it double it a second time if allowed or will it just double it once. this is with only one cast of it.

Comment: Have you taken our [tour]? :) The question and your clarifying comment look like two different questions: One about how to double damage and another asking if it doubles twice.

Comment: Strong Jaw increases damage by 'two sizes' unless the creature is Gargantuan. Are you specifically referring to Gargantuan creatures?

Answer (score -1):

#### Roll the dice twice, but not the bonuses.

[Strong Jaw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/strong-jaw/):

> Each natural attack that creature makes deals damage as if the creature were two sizes larger than it actually is. If the creature is already Gargantuan or Colossal-sized, **double the amount of damage dealt by each of its natural attacks instead.**  This spell does not actually change the creature’s size; all of its statistics except the amount of damage dealt by its natural attacks remain unchanged.

According to the rules on [Multiplying Damage](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/):

> Sometimes you multiply damage by some factor, such as on a critical hit. Roll the damage (with all modifiers) **multiple times and total the results.**

Note that in this case the spell only increases your damage dice, not the full damage of the attack, so you don't multiply the modifier here. It means, for example, that a gargantuan creature's slam (normally 2d6) increases to 4d6.

This matches the standard pattern of natural weapons scaling by size (e.g. 1d6→1d8→2d6→2d8 then 4d6→4d8), and it seems likely that the omission of this from the table is simply either due to lack of space or lack of an official designation for sizes over Colossal. The intent seems clear here: the correct damage dice for a Gargantuan+2 slam is 4d6, and this progression bears out if you look at the bite column.

You can't double twice with this spell. It only increases your damage dice to that of a creature two sizes larger than yourself, so a second casting wouldn't stack.

If something else doubles your damage, such as a critical hit, you roll that as you would normally.  The no-doubled-doublings situation doesn't apply here: your natural weapon's *damage dice* simply increased, and a critical hit doubles your *total damage*, so a 2d6 slam becomes a 4d6 slam and that becomes 8d6. It's as if a spell said "Your shortsword deals damage as if it were a greatsword," which would deal 2d6+modifiers damage or 4d6+(2x modifiers) on a critical hit.

Note that the spell only doubles damage of Gargantuan or larger creatures. Everyone else simply increases the dice as per the table.

Comment: That *note* is really important and changes the answer completely to be left at the end. The title is disagreeing with that part and the OP did not seem to be asking about gargantuan creatures.

Comment: Actually OP *does* seem to be talking about gargantuan creatures given their reference to doubling (the only place in the spell that's talked about). We should definitely ask for clarification on that point, though.

Comment: @Ifusaso, while he may seem confused about the spell wording, I dont think he is actually casting the spell on a gargantuan creature.

Comment: The question asks only about what happens "when you double damage", and I've answered accordingly. OP's question is entirely about the doubling mechanic. I noted at the end that only Gargantuan or larger creatures get doubling, as the question doesn't ask that so it's not primarily relevant, but I want to clarify in case OP or a future reader misunderstands the spell's effect on sub-Gargantuan creatures.

Comment: I agree, was just pointing out that the question was about the doubling. Clearing up confusion about the wording could very well be part of answering =